# Use the eclipse hibernate tool with hibernate spatial library

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, spatial, hibernate-tools, hibernate-spatial

There is some one that was able to configure the HQL tool of the eclipse hibernate tool? I have try to configure it using the JPA. My configuration generate all the Entity (that are observable in the configuration) and the connection to the database but the session factory return the following
Could not determine type for: org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType, at table:....

There is a way to solve this problem, maybe adding some library or configuration?

I am using Postgis DB and the proprietis of the configuration are:

```
<properties>    
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="off" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect" />
</properties>
```

Comment: What database are you using ?

Comment: I'm using a PostGIS DB with Hibernate 4.0

Comment: Post your dialect hibernate configuration

Comment: I'm using this dialect "org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect"